# flutter login with dio package

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, dio

i try to login to the api with dio and i cant handle it
my scenario is:
login with user name,password and server returned session like this:

```
{
    "function": "request_session_generate",
    "params": {
        "username": "myuser",
        "password": "mypass"
    }
}
```

and when send request post method returned session like below code:

```
{
    "result": 0,
    "data": {
        "session": "mysession...",
        "session_status": "generated"
    }
}
```

and second post method for validate this session ... put the session and otp code(google authenticator) like this:

```
{
    "function": "request_session_validate",
    "params": {
        "session": "mysession",
        "otp": "123456"
    }
}
```

when put the session in to the session params server returned:

```
{
    "result": 0,
    "data": {
        "session": "newSession",
        "session_status": "validated"
    }
}
```

how can get the session in the body response first method and use it in the second function for validate
my first function implement code :
class ApiClient {
final Dio _dio = Dio();

```
Future<Response?> login() async {
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post(
        'myserver/api',
        options: Options(
        headers: {
          "apikey": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        },
        ),
       data: {
       "function": "request_session_generate",
       "params": {
       "username": "myuser",
       "password": "mypass"
}
        },
                   
      );      
      
      //returns the successful user data json object
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        
       return response.data;
        
      }
     
     

    } on DioError catch (e) {
      //returns the error object if any
      return e.response!.data;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and my implemention for validate and not worked:

```
 Future<Response?> validate() async {
    try {
      Response responsevalidate = await _dio.post(
        'myserver/api',
       data: {
       "function": "request_session_validate",
       "params": {
        "session": "mysession",
        "otp": "123456"
       
}
        },
                   
      );      
      //returns the successful user data json object
      

        return responsevalidate.data;
        
    
   
      
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      //returns the error object if any
      return e.response!.data;
    }

    //IMPLEMENT USER LOGIN
}
```

how can get session in first function and use it in second function for validate?
use the json decode or something else ?
thank you for help me